# HPM Error occurred while proxying request from win desktop to service running on wsl

Tags: windows, http, proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, webpack-dev-server

I have the following error
`<e> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:8080/cpg/api/upload-code to http://localhost:5500/ [ECONNREFUSED] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)`

when trying to call from gui to service running on wsl2

Curl works ok

`C:\Program Files\Far Manager>curl -X "POST"   "http://localhost:5500/cpg/api/upload-code"                                                                     {"timestamp":"2022-12-28T06:38:11.314+00:00","path":"/cpg/api/upload-code","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","requestId":"38669ffa-23"}`

Swagger call also works on on desktop

When i run the same service on desktop it works

This is our proxy configuration https://github.com/saveourtool/save-cloud/blob/master/save-frontend/webpack.config.d/dev-server.js

How to fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.